# Facebook meta tags updating late

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return fbs_click(600, 400,'MyURL?image_name=<?php echo $row['image_name'] ?>&caption=<?php echo $row['caption']?>')" target="_blank" title="I just visited the Baidu Moustache Studio!"><img src="/assets/fbshare.png" alt="facebook share" height="22"></a>
```

Javascript:

```
 function fbs_click(width, height,url) {

    u=location.href;
    t= "Title";
    /*Url to update metadata */
    var updatemetadate = "https://graph.facebook.com/?id="+encodeURIComponent(url)+"&scrape=true"
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log("meta data updated!");
                    var leftPosition, topPosition;
                    //Allow for borders.
                    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
                    //Allow for title and status bars.
                    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
                    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
                     window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
                     return false;

            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",updatemetadate,true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
```

Now when I click share the image doesn't appear for the first few tries but comes later. Seems like the meta tags get updated late.

Any pointers?

Thanks,

p.s. Have tried the new Facebook(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web) redirect method as well. The result is the same.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#precaching